# Loops in Rmarkdown: How to make an in-text figure reference? Figure captions?

Tags: r, loops, knitr, r-markdown, reproducible-research

`{r setup, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, results="hide"}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
library(kfigr)
library(dplyr)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(pander)
library(ggplot2)`

### Question

Loops in rmarkdown: in-text figure reference? figure captions?

### Goal

Use a for loop to create sections with text, in-text results, and multiple figure references with associated figure captions in the figure list. The figure references/numbering should be seemless with figures numbered before and after these new sections.

*Note:* The figures referenced in the for loop are generated earlier in the text, saved as pngs, and then re-loaded. This might seem clunky for the purpose of this example, but the actual figs are maps and are slow to generate (I plan to comment out the loop that generates the figures once I have them how I want).

```
{r echo = FALSE, warnings=FALSE, message=FALSE, results="hide"}
```

#### Data: Each year we have a different number of strata, hence the need for a loop.

```
df <- rbind(
  data.frame(strata = rep("A", 10), x = rnorm(10, mean= 10), y = rnorm(10, mean = 15),z = rnorm(10, mean = 20)),
  data.frame(strata = rep("B", 10), x = rnorm(10, mean= 5), y = rnorm(10, mean = 10), z = rnorm(10, mean = 15)),
  data.frame(strata = rep("C", 10), x = rnorm(10, mean= 15), y = rnorm(10, mean = 20), z = rnorm(10, mean = 10)))
```

#### first_plot: the figure that should appear in the list before for loop creates the sections by strata

```
first_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, fill=strata)) + geom_histogram()
```

#### last_plot: the figure that should appear in the list after the for loop creates the sections by strata

```
last_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = strata, y = z)) + geom_boxplot()
```

#### Figure generation (this is the part that will be commented out later in my version once I have the maps how I want)

```
strat <- unique(df$strata)

for (i in seq_along(strat)) {
  sub <- df %>% filter(strata %in% strat[i])
  fig1 <- ggplot(sub, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
  ggsave(fig1, file=paste0("fig1_", strat[i], ".png"))
  fig2 <- ggplot(sub, aes(x = x, y = z)) + geom_point() 
  ggsave(fig2, file=paste0("fig2_", strat[i], ".png"))
}
```

#### Load the png's

```
df_figs <- list.files(pattern = "\\.png$")
for (i in df_figs){  
   name <- gsub("-",".",i)
   name <- gsub(".png","",name)  
   i <- paste(".\\",i,sep="")
   assign(name,readPNG(i))
}
```

### Introduction section

Some introductory text in the report and a figure `r figr('first_plot',TRUE, type='Figure')`.

````
```{r echo = FALSE, warnings=FALSE, message=FALSE, results = "asis"}

# Summary of results and image file names that will be references in text
results <- df %>% 
  group_by(strata) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% 
  mutate(fig1 = paste0("fig1_", strata),
         fig2 = paste0("fig2_", strata))

#Text template (each strata will have its own section)
template <- "# The %s stratum
The mean of *x* in %s stratum was %1.1f. Relationships between *x* and *y* and *x* and *z* can be found in `r figr('%s', TRUE, type='Figure')` and `r figr('%s', TRUE, type='Figure')`.

"

#Create markdown sections in for loop
for(i in seq(nrow(results))) {
  current <- results[i, ]
  cat(sprintf(template, 
              current$strata, current$strata, 
              current$x, 
              current$fig1, current$fig2))
}

#Also doesn't work:
template <- "# The %s stratum
The mean in %s stratum was %1.0f. Results can be found in "
template2 <- " and "
template3 <- ".

"

`figr('%s', TRUE, type='Figure')` and `figr('%s', TRUE, type='Figure')`."

#For loop
for(i in seq(nrow(results))) {
  current <- results[i, ]
  cat(sprintf(template,
            current$strata, current$strata,
            current$mean,
            current$fig_1, current$fig_2))
  print(paste0("`r figr(",paste0("'", current$fig1,"'"), TRUE, type='Figure'))
  cat(sprintf(template2))
  print(paste0("`r figr(",paste0("'", current$fig2,"'"), "TRUE, type='Figure'),`"))
  cat(sprintf(template3))
 }
```
````

### Conclusion section

Some discussion text in the report and figure `r figr('last_plot',TRUE, type='Figure')`.

### Figures

````
*NOTE:* I don't know how to automate the looped portion of the list of figures here, so I've done it by hand.

```{r 'first_plot', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="The caption for the first figure."}
suppressMessages(print(first_plot))
```

```{r 'fig1_A', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="Caption text for fig1_A."}
grid.raster(fig1_A)
```

```{r 'fig2_A', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="Caption text for fig2_A."}
grid.raster(fig2_A)
```

```{r 'fig1_B', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="Caption text for fig1_B."}
grid.raster(fig1_B)
```

```{r 'fig2_B', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="Caption text for fig2_B."}
grid.raster(fig2_B)
```

```{r 'fig1_C', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="Caption text for fig1_C."}
grid.raster(fig1_C)
```

```{r 'fig2_C', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="Caption text for fig2_C."}
grid.raster(fig2_C)
```

```{r 'last_plot', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6,  fig.cap="The caption for the last figure."}
suppressMessages(print(last_plot))
```
````

Comment: Sounds to me you could make good use of cache and knit_expand

Comment: @baptiste I explored knit_expand, but I don't see how it solves the `figr('plot',TRUE,type='Figure')` part of my problem.

`out = NULL
for (i in as.character(unique(results$strata))) {
out = c(out, knit_expand(text=c('#### The *{{i}}* strata',
                                '\n',
                                'The mean of *x* is ',
                                '{{paste(sprintf("%1.1f", results$x[results$strata==i]))}}',
                                '{{figr(sprintf("%s", results$fig1[results$strata==i]),TRUE,type="Figure")}}'
                                )))
}

cat(out)`

Comment: OK! Working.

`
 '({{figr(sprintf("%s", results$fig1[results$strata==i]),TRUE,type="Figure")}}).',
                                '\n'
                                
cat(out,sep="\n")`

Then make sure you have your fig caption calls at the end, which presumably you could also put in a loop?

Comment: FWIW the description of your workflow sounds rather unnatural and unnecessarily convoluted / fragile. It's hard to offer more precise guidance however, given the way your question is set. Typically the use of `cat()`, `assign()`, manual filenames etc. is a clear sign that you're doing something suboptimal in knitr. You may in fact be more comfortable working with the brew package to pre-process your knitr file, but from what I can tell several of the steps you're taking are unnecessary and just make your life harder (saving pngs and reloading them – sounds like a very bad idea to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLUTIONS

1. Use `knit_expand()`
2. Use `captioner` instead of `kfigr`
3. This numbers your figures (or tables) in text and at the end of your report.
4. This script shows you how to create markdown paragraphs in for loops that have in-text references to figures.
5. It also shows you how to create custom figure captions in for loops while retaining the number order.
6. If you show how to do #4 and #5 using `brew` I will give you all the SO points.

## Libraries

`library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(png)
library(grid)
library(pander)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(captioner)`

Create a `fig_nums()` function using the `captioner` package 
(https://github.com/adletaw/captioner/blob/master/vignettes/using_captioner.Rmd)

```
fig_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Figure")
```

## Data

**Each year we have a different number of strata, hence the need for a loop.**

```
df <- rbind(
  data.frame(strata = rep("A", 10), x = rnorm(10, mean= 10), y = rnorm(10, mean = 15), z = rnorm(10, mean = 20)),
  data.frame(strata = rep("B", 10), x = rnorm(10, mean= 5), y = rnorm(10, mean = 10), z = rnorm(10, mean = 15)),
  data.frame(strata = rep("C", 10), x = rnorm(10, mean= 15), y = rnorm(10, mean = 20), z = rnorm(10, mean = 10)))
```

first_plot: the figure that should appear in the list before for loop creates the sections by strata

```
first_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, fill=strata)) + geom_histogram()
fig_nums("first_plot", display = FALSE)
```

last_plot: the figure that should appear in the list after the for loop creates the sections by strata

```
last_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = strata, y = z)) + geom_boxplot()
```

## Figure generation

**Comment this section out once you have figs how you want. This step will not feel convoluted, unnatural, suboptimal, unnecessary, or like a very bad idea if you do a lot of mapping in R.**

```
strat <- unique(df$strata)

  for (i in seq_along(strat)) {
   sub <- df %>% filter(strata %in% strat[i])
   fig1 <- ggplot(sub, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
   ggsave(fig1, file=paste0("fig1_", strat[i], ".png"))
   fig2 <- ggplot(sub, aes(x = x, y = z)) + geom_point() 
   ggsave(fig2, file=paste0("fig2_", strat[i], ".png"))
 }
```

## Load the png's

```
df_figs <- list.files(pattern = "\\.png$")
for (i in df_figs){  
   name <- gsub("-",".",i)
   name <- gsub(".png","",name)  
   i <- paste(".\\",i,sep="")
   assign(name,readPNG(i))
}
```

## Introduction

Some introductory text in the report and a figure `r fig_nums("first_plot", display="cite")`.

Results and image file names that will be referenced in text:

````
```{r echo = FALSE, warnings=FALSE, message=FALSE, results = "asis"}

    results <- df %>% 
      group_by(strata) %>% 
      dplyr::summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% 
      mutate(fig1 = paste0("fig1_", strata),
             fig2 = paste0("fig2_", strata))

```

```{r run-numeric-md, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}

#The text for the markdown sections in for loop... the knit_expand() is the work-horse here.

out = NULL
for (i in as.character(unique(results$strata))) {
  out = c(out, knit_expand(text=c('#### The *{{i}}* strata',
                                  '\n',
                                  'The mean of *x* is ',
                                  '{{paste(sprintf("%1.1f", results$x[results$strata==i]))}}', '({{fig_nums(results$fig1[results$strata==i],display="cite")}}).',
                                  '\n'
  )))
}

```
````

## Creates section for each strata

```
`r paste(knit(text = out), collapse = '\n')`
```

## Conclusion

Some discussion text in the report and figure `r fig_nums("last_plot",display="cite")`.

## List of Figures

````
`r fig_nums("first_plot",caption="Here is the caption for the first figure.")`

```{r 'first_plot', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6}
suppressMessages(print(first_plot))
```

```{r figcaps, include=FALSE}
caps = NULL

for (i in as.character(unique(results$strata))) {
  caps = c(caps, knit_expand(  
    text=c({{fig_nums(results$fig1[results$strata==i], caption="Caption text for strata *{{i}}* goes here.")}},
           '``` {r {{results$fig1[results$strata==i]}}, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6}',
           {{paste0('grid.raster(',results$fig1[results$strata==i],')')}},
                                    '```',
           '\n')))
}

#DON'T FORGET TO UNLIST!
src <- unlist(caps)
```

`r paste(knit(text = src),sep='\n')`

`r fig_nums("last_plot", caption="The caption for the last figure.")`

```{r 'last_plot', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=6}
suppressMessages(print(last_plot))
```
````