# Show PNG images consecutively with loop in R Markdown chunk (HTML)

Tags: r, r-markdown

Can one use an R Markdown chunk loop to show multiple graphics files (e.g., PNG) consecutively (one above the other) in HTML output? This loop would identify the files in a vector, such as via `list.files()`.

I have experimented with no avail to uses of `writeLines("\n")`, `cat('\r\n\r\n')` per [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308960/loops-in-rmarkdown-how-to-make-an-in-text-figure-reference-figure-captions).

[This R Markdown code](https://gist.github.com/RickPack/c28f1b0e3ea569374ce23caae9c1d820) (formatted below but link is .Rmd) is a reproducible example with an attempt using `writeLines("\n")` and `cat('\r\n\r\n')`. Please note this copies 5 R logo PNG (only 12kb) file copies into your working directory.

````
---
title: "Stack Overflow Consecutive PNG"
author: "Rick Pack"
date: "11/20/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Copy a PNG file as multiple files

```{r png_copy, echo=FALSE}
for (q in 1:5) {
 file.copy(list.files(system.file("img", package = "png"), 
                      full.names = TRUE),
           getwd())
 file.rename("Rlogo.png", paste0("Rlogo_",q,".png"))
}
```

# Only one R logo shown instead of the five available
```{r png_show, echo=FALSE}
library(png)
# Providing the folder so you can delete the png files
# created above
print(getwd())
 all_img <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)[grepl(
     "Rlogo", list.files())]
 for (j in 1:length(all_img)) {  
 grid::grid.raster(readPNG(all_img[j]))
writeLines("\n")
cat('\r\n\r\n')  
cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
 }
```
````

[image: Showing only one PNG file appeared]

Answer (score 4):

You can use R Markdown syntax within the for loop instead of the `png` package. Given you have the images in the same directory as your Rmd, the following should work:

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
filelist <- c("Rlogo_1", "Rlogo_2", "Rlogo_3")

for(i in filelist) {
    cat(paste0("![](", i, ".png)"), "\n")
    cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
}
```
````

Output:
[image]
See this related question for more info: [Insert images using knitr::include_graphics in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268623/insert-images-using-knitrinclude-graphics-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: That solution printed strings like []./Rlogo_1.PNG but the link you provided gave the solution: just set the argument of knitr::include_graphics() to the vector containing the full paths to the image files. In my example: knitr::include_graphics(all_img) would appear in a chunk. Thanks!

Comment: It will print strings in the in-line output, but when you knit the document it should embed the images.

Comment: that was what I meant: the HTML showed only the strings.